# Elasticsearch - define query string as a filter in C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I have the next working elastic search query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "IsDeleted": false
              }
            },
            {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "payPlan.PayPlanData.*"
                  ],
                  "query": "(StartInterval :[1 TO 100] AND (EndInterval :[1 TO 9999999]))"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to define it as a c# `Nest.FilterDescriptor` element?
The main issue is defining a `QueryStringQuery` as a Filter

Comment: what version of NEST are you using?

Comment: NEST 1.7.1 , Elasticsearch.Net 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I managed to create to implement an elastic search  query string as a filter, I added other filters so you can see a real example:

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "NotSpan": true
          }
        },
        {
          "and": {
            "filters": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "(StartTimeAsNumber :[1 TO 12345] AND (EndTimeAsNumber :[12345 TO 9999999]))",
                            "default_field": "PayPlan.PayPlanData.*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "userRole": "admin"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

}
}